# Custom query to get post names beginning with a digit

Tags: php, mysql, wpdb

I'm implementing an A-Z index for a custom post type. I've got my links printing out the page and the query working for the letters. However, the numbers are tripping me up because I don't want them to work quite the same. I want the first link to read '0-9' and clicking it to show all posts that start with a number.

I think a wildcard is the answer, but it's not working the way I expect. Here's my function from my `functions.php`:

```
function test_first_letter( $sql ){
  global $wpdb;
  $first_letter = get_query_var( 'first_letter' );
  if( $first_letter ){
   if( $first_letter == 'num') :
     $sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->posts.post_name LIKE %s ", '5%');
   else:
     $sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->posts.post_name LIKE %s ", $first_letter.'%' );
   endif;
  }
  return $sql;
}
add_action( 'posts_where', 'test_first_letter' );
```

If the `$first_letter` query param is equal to 'num', then I want the query to look for all `post_names` starting with numbers `0-9`. However, this doesn't work:

```
$sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->posts.post_name LIKE %s ", '[0-9]*');
```

How can I get all posts where the post_name starts with any digit, 0-9?

Comment: You know there is a [`SUBSTR()` function in SQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substr)? Did you try that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The solution given by @RolandoMySQLDBA will give you all posts because you have a `*` and not a `+`. The `*` means to return zero or more matches, which is not what you want. In this case, you actually don't need either, but just to match the first character. Try this:

`$sql .= $wpdb->prepare( " AND $wpdb->posts.post_name REGEXP '^[0-9]'");`

Comment: +1 I went ahead and tested this and can verify that it does indeed return any and all posts beginning with a number.